# CSS Grid is not responsive on mobile-browsers

Tags: css, responsive-design, grid, css-grid, smartphone

I made a responsive website and works perfect when I re-size the browser, but the website dont work only on smartphones, only when I add *@media* it dont work on mobile-browsers

My CSS:

```
.Footer {
background: #222;
color: #fff;
padding: 2px;
align-items: center;
text-align: center;


@media(min-width: 600px) {
.Footer {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @media(max-width: 600px) {
//your code
}

or 
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
      //your code
    }

Comment: Which browser is this mobile? it could be unsupported.

Comment: All smartphones. 
When I use desktop browsers and re-size the browser it works. But when I use the smartphones does not work. Also dosent work on Google Chrome Toogle Device Toolbar! :(

Comment: take a look at minmax(), more info here https://www.rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2016/04/12/flexible-sized-grids-with-auto-fill-and-minmax/

Answer (score 5):

Use below media query. Since min-width: 600px will not detect your mobile device

```
@media(max-width: 600px) { 
    //your code 
}
```

or

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){ 
     //your code 
}
```

Or may be you have missed adding viewport you can use below one

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Your media query is working since it is stacking your elements. Please elaborate more how you want it to look?

Comment: Or check your viewport it has to be this for mobile responsive <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

Comment: Varsha Dhadge - OMG thank you I forgot to add the Viewport, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've confused min-width and max-width for the @media query.
So, try to use it this way:

```
@media(max-width: 600px) {
.Footer {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
}
```